# How to get URLs of page's requests?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, webrequest

I am working on a Chrome app and I need to find one of the request urls (the request is initiated in a JS script).

The page script after loading asks for `.../online_mektep/lesson/L_(page id)/index.json` and I need this `page id`. How can I find out the URL?

The only way I can see now is to modify the original script with a web request and just get the data before the request. Are there other ways?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if I completely understand what you're trying to accomplish, however: maybe you can add a listener and get the url. Then you can split the URL afterwards and get the route parameter you want

```
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(
  function(details) {
    console.log('onBeforeRequest', details.url);

    const yourUrl = details.url // example: ".../online_mektep/lesson/L_(page id)/index.json"
    const pathArray = yourUrl.split('/')
    console.log(pathArray[3].split('_')[1]) // should output (page id)
  },
);
```